# How can I detect on change event in ckeditor instance?

Tags: jquery, events, ckeditor

I want realize a "live" editing. When you editing content in ckeditor, the same content appear in other place (like div, p, etc.) in **same** time.

*Other interesting question*: when I removed display:none and visibility:hidden from text area, which attach to ckeditor, I saw, that it's empty. But if I try to get value of textarea ($('#text_editor').val()) there are content from ckeditor. What is the magic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting onChange events from a CKEditor using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the developers of ckeditor has developed an [onchange plugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.ca/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html).

Comment: I knew about it. There are 2 problems: when I changes font color or set bold text, for example, key event does not fired. The other problem is that getData() on key event return old data (on 1 key press).

Comment: The onchange plugin is [not maintained anymore](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.fr/2012/12/no-more-releases-for-onchange-plugin.html) and is not compatible with CKEditor 4  .

Comment: onchange event is supported in CKeditor 4+ versions. I used it and didn't required to add plugin. It worked perfectly