# ckeditor add "keyup" event

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

How can I attach "keyup" event to CKEdtior (I am using the jQuery adapter)

This is the code I am currently using:

```
$('#ckeditor textarea').ckeditor(function(editorInstance) {

    /* attaching "keyup" doesnt seem work so I have to stick with "key" */

    $('#ckeditor textarea').ckeditorGet().on('key', function(e) {
        /* do stuff ... */
    });

}, {
     skin : 'office2003'
});
```

The whole idea is to get the ckeditor content every time the content is changed.
Hope someone can help here.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [See my answer to this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391136/how-can-i-detect-on-change-event-in-ckeditor-instance/10404963#comment13422712_10404963

Comment: This will stop working if you use setData(). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054070/ckeditor-setdata-prevents-attaching-of-events-with-on-function

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this seems to work for me.

```
$('#ckeditor textarea').ckeditor(function() {

    var editor = $('#ckeditor textarea').ckeditorGet();        

    editor.on('contentDom', function() {
        editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
        /* do stuff */
    });

}, {
    skin : 'office2003'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how to resolve the issue it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable").keyup(function() {
    searchHighlight($(this).val());

  });

})

function searchHighlight(searchText) {

  if (searchText) {
    var content = $("p").text();
    var searchExp = new RegExp(searchText, "ig");
    var matches = content.match(searchExp);
    if (matches) {
      $("p").html(content.replace(searchExp, function(match) {
        return "<span class='light'>" + match + "</span>"

      }));
    }
  }
}
```