# CKEDITOR.setData prevents attaching of events with .on function

Tags: events, ckeditor

I have build a few custom plugins, but only one is listening to key events of the keyboard. 
Below in the code you can see the set-up to set the events. (and it's kinda basic)

Now i have the following problem that if i set my data with editor.setData in a instanceReady listener.that the .on functions aren't set.

I did try to replace the contentDom with the instanceReady event, but that doesn't fix it either.

if i set the data manualy with: editor.document.getBody().setHtml(html), there are no problems. and all events are attached without any problems..

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'myPlugin', {
    lang: '', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE% 

    init: function( editor ) {

        //Bind events if the Dom is ready!
        editor.on( 'contentDom', function()
        {
                //keydown
                editor.document.on('keydown', function(e)
                {
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Does the setData function only set the html or does it also reload the editor or something?

I did take a look at this [Ckeditor Source](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/editor.html#CKEDITOR-editor-event-setData)
But i think that this isn't code that has something to do with the setData function.

I'm not asking for a solution. I like to understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Editor#contentDom`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) is fired every time new inner document is set up. In framed editor `editor#setData()` replaces not only `body.innerHTML` but entire document, so `contentDom` is fired every time.

Thus, your code adds new listener on every `setData()` but you don't remove the old one. For unclear reasons none of these two listeners are now fired on `keydown`. I found out this recently and I cannot explain this fact.

Anyway, you need to detach all listeners on [`editor#contentDomUnload`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDomUnload). Fortunately, there's convenient way to do that by using [`editable#attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener).

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable();

    editable.attachListener( editor.document, 'keydown', function() {
        ...
    } );
} );
```

Listener will be automatically detached on next `contentDomUnload`.