# Listener Events being reset on setData and mode change, using CKEditor

Tags: javascript, events, ckeditor, listener, document

Whenever my script calls setData or changes the mode ("source", "WYSIWYG"), the Listeners for the Events I have assigned, are no longer called.

Research has taught me why and I have been experimenting with suggested solutions ([CKEDITOR.setData prevents attaching of events with .on function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054070/ckeditor-setdata-prevents-attaching-of-events-with-on-function)), including those from the official documentation (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom), but none of the resolutions work for me as documented, and I have no idea why.

Has anyone else here managed to resolve this issue? If so, I would be most grateful to find out how.

We are current running version 4.5.10 of CKEditor.

Thanking you in anticipation.
Ken.

Example:

```
// Works until setData() is called or until the view mode is changed ("WYSIWYG", "SOURCE).

ev.editor.document.on( 'keydown', function( evt )
{
    console.log("Key Down");
});

// This appears to be the recommended resolution however, this does not
    // work for me even prior to setData() being called of the view mode being changed.

    editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable();

    editable.attachListener( editor.document, 'keydown', function() {
    console.log("Key Down"); // Never executed
        } );
    } );
```

UPDATE: This solution (suggested by Dekel) looks to me as it should work. However, I suspect that I have not implemented it correctly so the Key Down event is not firing. Any thoughts on this:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('contentDom', function() {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].document.on('keydown', function(event) {
            console.log('key down')
        });
    });
}
```

UPDATE: Full code example. The event no longer appears to fire:

```
    <html>

<textarea name="editor1">
</textarea>

<textarea name="editor2">
</textarea>

<textarea name="editor3">
</textarea>

</html>

<script>

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  allowedContent: true
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
  allowedContent: true
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3', {
  allowedContent: true
});

for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('contentDom', function() {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].document.on('keydown', function(event) {
            console.log('key down')
        });
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Add an example...

Comment: // Works until setData() is called or until the view mode is changed ("WYSIWYG", "SOURCE).

ev.editor.document.on( 'keydown', function( evt )
{
    console.log("Key Down");
});

// This appears to be the recommended resolution however, this does not
// work for me even prior to setData() being called of the view mode being changed.

editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
var editable = editor.editable();

editable.attachListener( editor.document, 'keydown', function() {
console.log("Key Down"); // Never executed
  } );
  } );

Comment: Apologies for the format. I am new here. How would I go about getting newlines in the example?

Comment: Just edit your original question.

Comment: And a working example (http://jsfiddle.net / [so-snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is much better).

Comment: Thanks very much Dekel.

Comment: Regarding your update - please provide a complete working example (you can use jsfiddle.net for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took some time to understand what the problem is, but I think this is the solution that you are looking for.

You need to attach the `keydown` event everytime the DOM is ready. To do so - you need to listen to the `contentDom` event of the editor, and then to register the `keydown` event on the editor's document.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on('keydown', function(event) {
        console.log('key down')
    });
});
```

> In this example - `editor1` is the name of the ckeditor instance.

You can check this working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gad701dc/

In case you have multiple instances you will need to loop over them and add it to each of them:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('contentDom', function() {
        // The variable *this* here refers to the current instance of the ckeditor
        this.document.on('keydown', function(event) {
            console.log('key down')
        });
    });
}
```

> You need to access the relevant editor, you should do it with `this` instead of `CKEDITOR.instances[i]`, because the `i` variable will change before the call to the callback function will be made.

Comment: Excellent working example, thank you. There are multiple editor instances in use and I typically use CKEDITOR.currentInstance. However, this is now showing as undefined. I have tried adding your code to the instanceReady event, but the currentInstance is still showing as undefined. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Updated the answer, check the addition in the end

Comment: Thanks Dekel. I appreciate the quick response. I have responded via my original post.

Comment: Just a reminder I still haven't got this working yet. Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to help without knowing what the problem is. Create a jsfiddle with your code, demonstrate the problem...

Comment: The program it is a part of is huge. I did not write the code, nor do I have access to it all. The issue is that the event isn't fired using the code shown at the end of my OP.

Comment: If you will check the link in my example you will see that it works. If your code I written some other way - you might need to change some things. I don't know what the error you get/what are your variable names, if you have code errors and so on...

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I have been ill for the last 5 days. I unmarked the answer as correct as I had more that one tab open to this question and on seeing an unmaked version of the question, I clicked it again. I guess that unmaked it. I will resolve that in a minute. In respect to the issue of not being able to get the code to work, I will attempt to update your jsfiddle as I could not find the necessary URL to make CKEditor work in my version. Thanks.

Comment: Not surprisingly, I could not update your jsfiddle, so I have added the full example in my OP. The result is that the event never appears to be fired. Any ideas on this one Dekel?

Comment: I don't see the "full example" in you OP. Please double check (I see only the javascript code, which you said didn't work... while in my example it works perfectly), so I guess you have some other error there.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get the code formatted correctly.

Comment: Ok. found the problem in the code :) will update the answer in the next few minutes

Comment: Great job! Thanks Dekel.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Will appreciate a vote on the question when you have enough reputation (you need a minimum of 15 for that).

Comment: I also rolled-back your update of the question - there is no need for this kind of update since there is an answer that is marked as the correct answer.