# CKEDITOR : How do set `contentdom` after every SetData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am creating a CKEditor plugin and I face some issues on this.

**Model of My Plugin:**

```
 CKEDITOR.plugins.add("myplugin", {
    //for lang,require,icon
    init:function(a){
       editor.on('contentDom', function () {
            editor.document.on('key', function (evt) {
                console.log("Key Pressed"); 
            });
       }); 
    }
 });
```

This is **Working Fine**.But,my problem is `setData`.

I am setting data when the user is clicking a file.

After `setData` the `key` event is not Working.

Is there any way to attach the listener to document after every `setData()` within plugin file?

And what are the other type of methods which are used in CKEditor like `init` ?

**(OR)**

Is there any way to `setData()` without affecting `contentdom,key` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the Answer.

Refer the below Question

[CKEDITOR.setData prevents attaching of events with .on function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054070/ckeditor-setdata-prevents-attaching-of-events-with-on-function/16058877)

And goes to the Document in CKEditor Docs Page.

[#contentDomUnload](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editable.html#method-attachListener)

Finally My Code Like this,

```
editor.on('contentDom', function () {
            var editable = editor.editable();
            editable.attachListener(editable, 'keyup', function (evt)  {
                  console.log('for key events');
            });

            editable.attachListener(editable, 'mousedown', function (evt) {
                  console.log('for click events');
            });
});
```

And It worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the listener to the editor and not to the document. That way it wil not get removed when document is removed:

```
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( e ) {
    editor.on( 'key', function( e ) { 
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-key

Comment: I try this way already.If you are doing this way then events fired so Quickly.So, this didn't work for me.Thank's for your Time friend