# Dynamic CKEditor jQuery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect on change event in ckeditor instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391136/how-can-i-detect-on-change-event-in-ckeditor-instance)

I have generated CKEDITORS dynamically as much i like using a button through jquery. I generated it as like this.
Add is the id of the button and config is the array.

```
$('#add').click(function(){

$('<div class = "editors name="dynamic[]"><div class="field" cols="20" id="'+id+'" name="dynamic[]"      rows="10"></div><div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');

$('.field:last').ckeditor(config);
```

The '.field:last' is used to create a new ckeditor after the already created editors ,  every time button is clicked.

But how can i attach an change function or keypress or keydown function with these editors. 
I have done it in javascript where i have fixed static editors. Like the code in below. But how can i do it in jquery.

Runtime change event on CKEditor through JavaScript.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {

e.editor.on('change', function (ev) {

   var temp = ev.editor.getData();
   alert(temp);

}); });
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't use all caps. It is usually considered very unpolite. I edited your post for you.