# simple way to add onchange event to ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Is there a nice and easy quick way to add an onchange event to the CKeditor.

I would like to do something when ever the text changes? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
   $(function () {
        var config = {
            toolbar:
                    [
                        ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList']
                    ],
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            resize: false
        };

        $('.jquery_ckeditor').ckeditor(config);


        CKEDITOR.instances[0].on('change', function () {
            alert("test");
        });





    });

    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea class="jquery_ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It already has a whole API to tap into, including [events](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.event.html)

Comment: hi yes I know but I dont understand

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting onChange events from a CKEditor using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function() { 
    console.log("TEST");
});
```

Comment: CKEDITOR.instances.<YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME>.on(--change event--). You can give an instance name for your CKEDITOR like CKEDITOR.replace(<YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME>)

Comment: @XPD. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**. Excuse me, my previous version of answer was not correct.

As I have found out it's no a standart onchange event for CKEDITOR. Instead of it you can emulate it with help of another events for textarea. For example, you can use the event 'keydown'.

Try it by changing the code for CKEDITOR to the next one:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[idOfTextarea].document.on('keydown', function() {alert('text')});
```

[More info](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html)

Comment: what does the [0 ] mean - can it to use "jquery_ckeditor" . thanks for the help

Comment: @Hello-World It means the first (and only) instance of CKEDITOR.

Comment: @Hello-World Try to do it after document is complete. See my changed answer please. Is it OK now?

Comment: i now I get this error - will update my code now at the top - thanks for the help -- Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'on': object is null or undefined

Comment: @Hello-World I have corrected my answer, please see the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[0]
```

instances is an object, and you can get value (editor) by the key.

Replace it with

```
CKEDITOR.instances[yourInstanceName]
```

Answer (score 0):

`CKEditor`  provides various `events` which is mentioned in their [Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-change).

`Change Event`: Fired when the content of the editor is changed.

Due to performance reasons, it is not verified if the content really changed. The editor instead watches several editing actions that usually result in changes. This event may thus in some cases be fired when no changes happen or may even get fired twice.

If it is important not to get the change event fired too often, you should compare the previous and the current editor content inside the event listener. It is not recommended to do that on every change event.

Please note that the change event is only fired in the wysiwyg mode. In order to implement similar functionality in the source mode, you can listen for example to the key event or the native input event (not supported by Internet Explorer 8).

```js
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function () {
    // operations
});
```

Here `editor1` is the `id` of the `textarea` or the `instance` of the element.