# I cant get my addEventListener to work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have this function in a separate file, and it loads when another javascript function is called. I need to do this in order to reach the "word_number" id which a javascript text editor implements. This editor loads and then i call my function."

```
function wordsChange() {
if (window.addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('word_number').addEventListener('change', wordsK, false);
} else {
    document.getElementById('word_number').attachEvent('onchange', wordsK);
}}

function wordsK(){
alert('im reading');}
```

The wordsChange function gets called, but it dont trigger the wordsK function. I dont know what im doing bad, and appreciate any suggestions.

Sorry for the lack of information.
Im trying to use the output from the docksoft_stat plugin for CKeditor that shows a word counter on the bottom.
I need this info to operate with. 
Thank you all for all the quick answers.

Comment: Use keydown/keyup events instead of change.

Comment: As your code currently is, `wordsK` should only execute after `#word_number` changes. Do you want it to execute when `wordsChange` is run?

Comment: i want it to execute when #word_number changes, and its not a textarea, its a output fom the editor. (im using CKEditor and the id is from a plugin that shows the words number on the editor´s footer)

Comment: Is it possible that `word_number` is not a element but a js-variable?

Comment: This might be useful,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery

Comment: This might be useful,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!!**

I just find an alternative solution for the issue. As i couldnt read the value of word_number on change event i installed the @Alfonso (Gracias!) onchange plugin for the CKeditor and used to trigger my function:

```
function wordsChange() {
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {
    alert('text changed!');
});
}}
```

It works ferfectly and now i can do whatever i want.
thank you all again for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: You are using a `<textarea>`.
[According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) the change-event will not be fired when you type in the `<textarea>`-field. It will only be fired when you click somewhere else but the `<textarea>`.

As jrath suggested, use the `keydown`-event instead. This one will be fired each time a key has been pressed while the textare-element has focus.

Using the `keyup` event may not always work. Possible situation: You focus the `textarea` by clicking in it, then press a key (`keydown` will be fired), then click somewhere outside the `textarea` while still holding the key, then releasing the key. The `keyup` event will not be fired since the `textarea` field has already lost focus by clicking somewhere else.

Comment: as i said before its not a textarea field,  its an output fom the editor. (im using CKEditor and the id is from a plugin that shows the words number on the editor´s footer).

Comment: What does "output" mean? What kind of element is `word_number` then? What events are configured for that element?

Comment: just edited my question explaining better the issue. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your`wordsChange()` function anywhare. try below code :

```
'function wordsChange() {
if (window.addEventListener) {
document.getElementById('word_number').addEventListener('change', wordsK, false);} else {
document.getElementById('word_number').attachEvent('onchange', wordsK);}
}

function wordsK(){alert('im reading');}
// add below line to your code;
wordsChange();
```

It will work;

Thanks

Comment: wordsChange its called from another function which waits the editor (CKEditor) to load.

Comment: Is CKEditor getting loaded via ajax call? And which field is being edited and which is the field being updated on any changes ?
Can please post the complete code, so I can try replicating that issue.

Comment: just edited my question explaining better the issue. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('word_number').addEventListener('change', wordsK, false);

This will only trigger if the text box get focus out.

You can try with binding 'keypress' or 'keyup' or 'keydown' event otherwise bind an event with jQuery as like below
$(document.getElementById('word_number')).on("input",wordsK);

this might be useful for ckeditor

[Detecting onChange events from a CKEditor using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery)

Comment: thank you very much. i tink i can solve this with other approach. Ill let you know when im done.