# Plugin for text transformation in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is it possible to automatically replace some text with some other directly while typing in CKEditor.

Examples would be to directly replace:

- "Mr" --> "Mister"
- "Mrs" --> "Madam"
- "BC" --> "business card"

I know I could do this while saving or while typing, etc., but it would be very nice to get the correct result with a configuration interface to save those words.

Thankful for any pointers!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. CKEditor has change events too

Comment: Can you give me any plugin can do this please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

which version of CKEditor you are using ?
maybe you can found a callback function in there documentation